# Update viewpager fragments when user set filters are changed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My activity has a fab which lets the user filter to the genres of movies he wants to see in each list.

The "UpcomingFragment" has a method "loadReleaseData" which fetches the data with the updated genres filters for the fragment's current month. The same "UpcomingFragment" fragment is repeated 14 times, each fragment is associated with a month.

For example, the first fragment in the viewpager will show the movie releases of the current month (august 2018) and the next "UpcomingFragment" in the viewpager will show the releases of the next month (September 2018).

I need to update all fragments content whenever a genre change is detected (a new one is added to the shared pref or an old one gets removed)

Here's my fragment with the viewpager which contains all "UpcomingFragment":

```
public class UpcomingViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {

    public ViewPager mViewPager;

    public UpcomingViewPagerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upcoming_view_pager, container, false);
        // Viewpager
        mViewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(-1);
        // Get TabLayout from Main
        TabLayout tabLayout = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).mTabLayout;
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        final SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat monthFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
        // Add 11 months [Maximum] to show the releases for the next year [14 fragments in total]
        // First page recently released [-1] gets the last month of the current month
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new UpcomingGamesFragment(), monthFormatter.format(calendar.getTime()) + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), "recently");
        // Set it back to normal
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            String title = monthFormatter.format(calendar.getTime()) + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            // m_yyyy
            String queryId = (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "_" + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new UpcomingGamesFragment(), title, queryId);
            calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        }
        // Last page: Coming in the future, everything after the last 11th month
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new UpcomingGamesFragment(), "Near future", "future");
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        // Because the first page will always be the recently released
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
        // Listener to update
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                ((UpcomingGamesFragment) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCurrentFragment()).loadReleaseData(0);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look at the observable pattern. Google has a library for this - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: @JessonAtherton Who do you think will be the observable in this case? I know the observer will be the "UpcomingFragment" class

Comment: I imagine the Genre would be observed and when a new Genre is set you would update your filters based on the result

Comment: Yes makes sense, thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem, good luck!